# Differentiability if partial derivatives are zero

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

At a given point , If partial derivatives of the function are continuous, then function is differentiable .. so, if partial derivatives are zero or a constant, which are continuous, is function always differentiable ? 
Thank you

Comment: If all the first order partial derivatives are constant on an open domain, the function is differentiable. If the open domain is connected, the function is affine on this domain.

Comment: Are you saying that the partial derivatives are constant everywhere?

Comment: Yes .. Partial derivatives are constant